# Why appear NA's in my results when I save it in a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a problem and it is that when I run this monte carlo method to aprox the result of that multiple integral, the result is a matrix of NA's and just appear the last one iteration in my matrix 'result' ... here is the code:

```
fun <- function(x) exp(-x[1]-x[2])
k <- seq(10,1000,10)

for(i in 1:length(k)){
  result <- matrix(nrow = length(k), ncol = 2)
  U <- matrix(runif(n = 2*k[i]), ncol = 2)
  aprox <- mean(apply(X = U, MARGIN = 1, FUN = fun))
  result[i,1] <- k[i]
  result[i,2] <- aprox
}
result
```

Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fun <- function(x) exp(-x[1]-x[2])
k <- seq(10,1000,10)

result <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(k), ncol = 2)

for(i in 1:length(k)){
  U <- matrix(runif(n = 2*k[i]), ncol = 2)
  aprox <- mean(apply(X = U, MARGIN = 1, FUN = fun))
  result[i,1] <- k[i]
  result[i,2] <- aprox
}
result
       [,1]      [,2]
  [1,]   10 0.4485121
  [2,]   20 0.3622201
  [3,]   30 0.3880991
  [4,]   40 0.3968607
  [5,]   50 0.3702156
  [6,]   60 0.3717430
  [7,]   70 0.3850652
```

`result` matrix definition should be outside the loop

Comment: hahaha thanks i'm so distracted and I miss that, again thank you to answer.